# How position HStack in bottom of my screen no use the spacer()

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

[image]

I want move the HStack in bottom of my screen no use the spacer() because when use the spacer move the logo for top of my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without using Spacer:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Image")
                Text("Some text")
            }.frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            HStack {
                Text("Bottom")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for no spacer, but this code shows you can use them without your logo going to the top of the screen. Alternatively you can use ".position(CGPoint(...))"

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        VStack (alignment: .center) {
            Image("your-image").resizable().frame(width: 90, height: 95)
            Text("TCheck time").font(.title).foregroundColor(.gray)
        }.padding()
        Spacer()
        HStack (alignment: .bottom) {
            Text("2020 SplitWay").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}
}
```